# ColdFusion not "seeing" my components

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfc

I have a directory structure similar to

> C:...\wwwroot\project\testPage.cfm

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Page</title>

</head>

<cfset this.mappings["/local"] = getDirectoryFromPath(getCurrentTemplatePath()) />

<cfform name="myform"> 

    Pick as many as you like: 
    <cfinput id="pickers4" name="pickmany" type="checkbox" value="Apples"> 
        <label for="pickers4">Apples</label> 
    <cfinput id="pickers5" name="pickmany" type="checkbox" value="Oranges"> 
        <label for="pickers5">Oranges</label> 
    <cfinput id="pickers6" name="pickmany" type="checkbox" value="Mangoes"> 
        <label for="pickers6">Mangoes</label> 
    <br/> 
    <cfinput name="pickmany-selected" bind="cfc:TestCFC.One({myform:pickmany})"><br />

</cfform> 

</body>
</html>
```

> C:...\wwwroot\project\TestCFC.cfc

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cfscript>
    remote function One(whatever){
        return whatever;    
    }
    </cfscript>
</cfcomponent>
```

and for some reason the ColdFusion server won't "see" my component. I get this error.

[image]

I wasn't using mappings as my component was located in the same directory as my page. This worked at one point, and it seems as though the CF server has just dropped a setting or something. Anyone have some idea as to why this is happening?

Comment: If you go to `yourproject.com/project/TestCFC.cfc`, do you get redirected to the CF Admin to view the docs for the CFC? Have you verified that your path is really what you expect it to be? I would think Jason's fix would do it... maybe try `local.project.TestCFC` since you're creating a local mapping?

Comment: I get a gray error box saying the CFC can't be found. I have tried with/without local as well as with/without that mapping. When it was working I wasn't using a mapping. This machine has been blue screening lately, I am going to attribute my problems to that and rebuild my computer. I'll let you know if the code works on a fresh install of ColdFusion.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since your CFC is located in C:...\wwwroot\project\TestCFC.cfc wouldn't the path (FQN) be project.TestCFC?

Did you try this:

```
<cfinput name="pickmany-selected" bind="cfc:project.TestCFC.One({myform:pickmany})"><br />
```

Comment: Yes, I had tried that, didn't work. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, per-se; but a suggestion for investigation.

What's the URL that is actually being requested by the browser under the hood?  And what's the HTTP error you get?

Also: I doubt CF mappings are relevant here because JS is mapping a client-side HTTP request, and CF mappings are just so CF can access resources on its local system (ie: server side).  If you need to map anything to the location of the URL, it needs to be a web server virtual directory, not a CF mapping.